# Personalize component to show a different layout

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

I have a page that has a form displayed on it, I need to personalize the page so that once the user submits the form, I should hide the form and show a completely different component (for example a cards component). I tried to follow the steps in this [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/Users/90/sitecore-experience-platform/walkthrough--personalizing-components.html#personalize-the-content) but it doesn't work, I think it's because the cards rendering that I'm trying to show when the rule is triggered is not compatible with the forms rendering.

Is there another way to achieve this using personalization?

Comment: Is this page behind login ? I am asking as you will need some way to remember that form has been submitted on this page by the user. It can be server side session, cookie, local storage etc. You can save an identifier on form submit and create a personalization rule to read that identifier value to hide/show components.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with personalization:

1. Add both components to the page
2. For the form component use personalization rule to hide the form if the form was already filled in the past:

[image: form personalization in Sitecore]

3. For the Cards rendering use personalization and hide by default and only show if the form was will already in the past[image]